# Javascript is not working innerhtml

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

I have simple javascript. I just need to get a date from a textbox and pass to label for other purpose. But here is the problems. I able to alert the that get from textbox but when i try to load it into label. It show empty.

```
function get_WlcData() {
    if ($('#DropDownList1').val() == 'Required') {
        document.getElementById("wlcboard").style.display = '';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("wlcboard").style.display = 'none';
    }    
    var x = document.getElementById("reservation").value;
    alert(x);
    document.getElementById("lblreserve").innerHTML = "testing";
    document.getElementById("lblreserve1").innerHTML = "testasdad";
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
 <input type="text" name="reservation" id="lblreserve" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" />
 <asp:Label ID="lblreserve1" runat="server" CssClass="labelForm" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: check the **developer** tools console for errors ... do you load jquery library? also, where do you call the function `get_WlcData`?

Comment: I'm such a derp ... `asp:Label ID="lblreserve1"` ... the resulting ID **wont** be `lblreserve1` for a start (because that's how ASP "works") - and, `Visible="False"` will mean that the "control" wont even be in the rendered HTML (in other words, that whole Label control won't even exist on the browser)

Comment: Hi, I have tried to change the visible to true it still the same. However, get_WlcData is called when user choose on the dropdownlist.

Comment: `I have tried to change the visible to true it still the same` - of all the things I've said, you pick on that one ... have you checked the console? do you load jquery? did you read the bit where I said the ID for that ASP:label would not be what you expect? - I know changing "false" to "true" is very easy, but that is only a small (but very important) part of the issue

Comment: In developer tools console error -  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at get_WlcData (EMForm.aspx:314)
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (EMForm.aspx:496)

Comment: exactly, because the ID for the ASP:Label will **not be** `lblreserve1` - because ASP mangles ID's ... try `document.getElementById(<% =lblreserve1.ClientID %>").innerHTML = "testasdad";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that comes to mind is that your referencing an ID that doesn't exist

```
var x = document.getElementById("reservation").value;
```

In this code you're looking for the value of something with id="reservation" but that element does not exist in the HTML you have provided. Would that not be getElementById("lblreserve") - as this is the ID of the input element?

It also may not be showing because your label is set to Visible="False", meaning the value might be setting but it doesn't appear because it's hidden from view.

Comment: Hi, the reservation is exist  <input type="text" name="reservation" id="reservation" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" />

Comment: It able to 'alert(x)' and showing me the correct answer. the visible is not related. even though i change it to true.  In my javascript it should able to showing text  '= "testing";' or '= "testasdad"'

Comment: @jaromanda-x is correct, in that ASP mangles ID's so it's likely that your javascript isn't working because the labels ID has been changed before it gets pushed to the page.

One solution would be to use getelementsbyname and then use a loop but it will return an object that you then have to iterate through which is a pain. The suggestion of using `document.getElementById(<% =lblreserve1.ClientID %>").innerHTML = "testasdad";` should certainly work

Comment: Hi, even though i using the normal html that id is not mangles. <input type="text" name="reservation" id="lblreserve" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" />

Comment: @user3759016 when you load your page, right click the label and inspect element (works well in Google Chrome). in the Element viewer, does the input still have the same ID or is the ID different once it's rendered to the page?

Answer (score 0):

first you have to show the hidden label and then write text to that label

```
  document.getElementById("lblreserve").style.display= "inline";
 document.getElementById("lblreserve").innerHTML = "testing";
```

writing to textbox value using

```
document.getElementById('lblreserve').value='new value';
```